# multipart identifier could not be bound on sql with cases when

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, case-when

hello everyone i have a sql query in which i am using case when and inner join,

the problem i am facing is i am getting the error of multipart identifier

here is my sql query

```
SELECT 
CASE when row_num = 1 THEN bill_id ELSE NULL 
END as bill_id, listinvoice.sonvinid,
listinvoice.date, listinvoice.brandname,listinvoice.venue,listinvoice.zone,
listinvoice.location,
listinvoice.instructore,listinvoice.paymentid,listinvoice.amount
FROM (
select bill_id, row_number()
 over
 (partition by bill_id order by listinvoice.date asc)
  row_num, listinvoice.sonvinid, tid, listinvoice.date
  , listinvoice.brandname,listinvoice.venue,
  listinvoice.zone,listinvoice.location,
  listinvoice.instructore,paymentid,amount
from listinvoice
inner join sonvininsert
on 
sonvininsert.sonvinid=listinvoice.sonvinid
 where 
tid in (select tid from trainerdetails where empname='andrew charles')
and listinvoice.[date] between
'2015-02-02' and '2017-02-02'
)data
```

and my error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier
>   "listinvoice.sonvinid" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier "listinvoice.date" could not be
>   bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier
>   "listinvoice.brandname" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier "listinvoice.venue" could not be
>   bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier
>   "listinvoice.zone" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 The multi-part identifier "listinvoice.location" could not be
>   bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier
>   "listinvoice.instructore" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier "listinvoice.paymentid"
>   could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part
>   identifier "listinvoice.amount" could not be bound.

what will be the possible fixes for this?

Comment: Try changing all of the first `SELECT`s to `data.columnnames` from `listinvoice.columnnames`

Comment: From what you posted there is no need for this to have a subquery at all.

Comment: what will be data here?

Comment: @SeanLange This is off topic, but you have a really great understanding of queries and aggregation in general without visually seeing data samples... it is amazing. How do you do it?

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't see the part where you were referencing your row_number column in the outer query. But others have already answered your question.

Comment: @Simon thank you for the kind words. Funny you say that because that is how I feel about so many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct except for the alias of the inner query and requires a single change:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        when row_num = 1 
        THEN bill_id 
        ELSE NULL 
    END as bill_id, 
    listinvoice.sonvinid,
    listinvoice.date,
    listinvoice.brandname,
    listinvoice.venue,
    listinvoice.zone,
    listinvoice.location,
    listinvoice.instructore,
    listinvoice.paymentid,
    listinvoice.amount
FROM (
    select 
        bill_id, 
        row_number() over
            (partition by bill_id order by listinvoice.date asc) row_num, 
        listinvoice.sonvinid, 
        tid, 
        listinvoice.date , 
        listinvoice.brandname,
        listinvoice.venue,  
        listinvoice.zone,
        listinvoice.location,
        listinvoice.instructore,
        paymentid,
        amount
    from listinvoice
        inner join sonvininsert
            on 
            sonvininsert.sonvinid=listinvoice.sonvinid
    where 
        tid in 
            (
                select 
                    tid 
                from trainerdetails 
                where empname='andrew charles'
            )
    and listinvoice.[date] 
        between '2015-02-02' and '2017-02-02'
        )listinvoice -- change required here to correct the alias
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE when row_num = 1 THEN bill_id ELSE NULL 
END as bill_id, data.sonvinid,
data.date, data.brandname,data.venue,data.zone,
data.location,
data.instructore,data.paymentid,data.amount
FROM (
select bill_id, row_number()
 over
 (partition by bill_id order by listinvoice.date asc)
  row_num, listinvoice.sonvinid, tid, listinvoice.date
  , listinvoice.brandname,listinvoice.venue,
  listinvoice.zone,listinvoice.location,
  listinvoice.instructore,paymentid,amount
from listinvoice
inner join sonvininsert
on 
sonvininsert.sonvinid=listinvoice.sonvinid
 where 
tid in (select tid from trainerdetails where empname='andrew charles')
and listinvoice.[date] between
'2015-02-02' and '2017-02-02'
)data -- here is where you named your table
```

Your `SELECT` statement is pulling from a derived table you named `data`, so you will need to reference the table name appropriately.